# .htaccess redirect page with variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please help to fix these redirects:

**Redirect 1.** category/?option=value  **=>** domain.com/category/page.html

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^option=value(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/$ http://domain.com/category/page.html%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

**Redirect 2.** category/sub-%26-category/?option=value **=>**  domain.com/category/page1.html

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^option=value(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/sub-\x26-category/$ http://domain.com/category/page1.html%1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `?` in target URI to strip off any existing query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=value(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/$ /category/page.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=value(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/sub-\x26-category/$ /category/page1.html? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Make sure these rules are placed above other internal routing rules.

Comment: > Make sure these rules are placed above other internal routing rules.

Comment: thanks a lot, I added redirect to the start of .htaccess and they work now